# Collaborate to remove some meta-tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I just noticed the tag [contribute](/questions/tagged/contribute). Some seem to be about Adobe Contribute, which I'll go through now and retag to [adobe-contribute](/questions/tagged/adobe-contribute) if appropriate [**edit**: done], but other uses of it seem meta to me. It's not too big - only 30 questions, but the quality of those questions is suspect, so it might need a little more effort to deal with than the number would suggest.

Following the line of reasoning that led to [contribute](/questions/tagged/contribute) I also checked:
[collaboration](/questions/tagged/collaboration) (~350)
[submission](/questions/tagged/submission) (~250)
[submit](/questions/tagged/submit) (2.5k)

- Collaboration I imagine is mostly used as a search term by people looking for tools, i.e. off-topic?
- Submission seems to be mostly about submitting to app stores - i.e. useless on its own.
- Submit has a tag wiki and claims to be about submitting forms, but there's also a separate [form-submit](/questions/tagged/form-submit) tag with 1k+ questions. (I'm not convinced either are useful, personally, but perhaps others can persuade me of the need). Not sure on the best course of action for this one.

Comment: Burnination is the term you're looking for.